# Cannot send notifications to specific user_id using Yii2 webzop/yii2-notifications

Tags: notifications, yii2

I am using https://github.com/webzop/yii2-notifications to send notifications in Yii2 but I can't figure out how to send a notification to a specific user id? In the database there is a table called `notifications` which has a column named `user_id`, but the column is always `0`.

I am using the following snippet to send a notification

```
$user = User::findOne(123);
AccountNotification::create(AccountNotification::KEY_RESET_PASSWORD, ['user' => $user])->send();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this scenario, here is the part that I was missing;

`$notification->setUserId($id);`

Full code snippet:

```
$user = User::findOne(['id' => $id]);
$notification = AccountNotification::create(AccountNotification::KEY_RESET_PASSWORD, ['user' => $user]);
$notification->setUserId($id);
$notification->send();
```